# Is the weighted transitive reduction problem NP-hard?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, np-hard

The transitive reduction problem is to find the graph with the smallest number of edges such that $G^t = (V,E^t)$ has the same reachability as $G=(V,E)$.

When $E^t \subseteq E$ it is NP-complete. When $E^t \subseteq V\times V$ but not necessarily of $E$, this problem is polynomial time solvable. I am wondering about the edge-weighted version without the subset requirement.

My initial feeling was that with weights, the problem is very similar to TSP. The greedy approach seems to be invalid when adding weights. But several articles (http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/26/17/2160.short for instance) seems to imply that the problem is solvable in polynomial time.

If it was easy, then you could just add arbitrarily large edge weights to each edge not in the original edge set and keep the weights at unity for the others. Then you would have a polynomial time algorithm for the subset constrained problem.

So this should mean it HAS to be NP, right?

edit: Are there immidiate examples that come to mind of problems whose unweighted version is easy, but gets hard when weights are added?

edit: by edge-weighted, I mean we are interested in finding the graph with the smallest total edge cost

Comment: I'm actually going to post a related, more general question which I will link here when I'm done.

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40475/lower-bounding-the-minimum-equivalent-graph - It's not the same question but it is related...

Comment: I can't tell what you are asking.  What is your question?  Are you asking whether it is in NP?  whether it is NP-hard?  It looks like you have some basic confusions about the definitions.  What do you mean by "when ...?"  Those are two different problems; which one are you asking about?  Note that if the unweighted version is NP-hard, the weighted version is, too (as the unweighted version is a special case).  Your question is not at all clear -- please edit.  (Also, why isn't this a duplicate of http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/40475/755?)

Comment: "When $E^t\subseteq E$ it is NP-complete. When $E^t\subseteq V\times V$". $E^t$ is a minimum-weight relation whose transitive closure includes $E$ so $E^t$ is *always* a subset of $E$. The edge relation of a graph is *always* a set of pairs of vertices.

Comment: @DavidRicherby What? In the transitive reduction problem you're free to add edges that wasn't in the original graph. E isn't the closure, it's the original edge set.

Comment: "When..." is referring to an additional constraint on the problem. We require $E' \subseteq E$ in the MEG case, which makes the problem hard.

Comment: @luegofuego Yes, you're right (though it sounds like you're going to have a lot of zero-weight edges added in the weighted case). But it's still the case that $E^t$ cannot fail to be a subset of $V\times V$, right? You've defined it to be the edge relation of a graph with vertex set $V$.

Comment: It's always a subset of $V \times V$, just not necessarily of $E$

Comment: Please edit the question to state precisely what you mean by "the weighted version".  You never actually give the problem statement.  Your self-answer below suggests you intended to allow providing weights for non-edges (for pairs $(i,j)$ of vertices that are not an edge in $G$), which is  a bit subtle: usually weighted graph problems only allow us to specify weights on the edges.  If that was the intent, I suggest editing the question to give a clearer statement of the problem you were asking about, so this is more likely to be helpful to others in the future.

Comment: Well. If you let the edge weights of edges not included in $E$ be $\infty$, then it doesn't really matter if we remove them or not. I'm saying that if ANY (positive edge weight) weighted transitive reduction problem is solvable polynomial time, then the case with arbitrarily large edge weights is also solvable in poly time. If that is true, then the MEG is also solvable in poly time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $G=(V,E)$. Let $w_{ij} = 1$ if $e_{ij} \in E$ and let $w_{ij} \gg 1$ if $e_{ij} \notin E$. This choice of weights correspond exactly to the constraint $E' \subseteq E$. Thus, if the weighted transitive reduction is polynomial time solvable, then so is the minimum equivalent graph problem.